# File Reader progress bar is not displaying progress value correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I have some photo upload with FileReader. This works ok, but I want to add some progress bar to my upload and that part is not so perfectly. It still has 0% value... Can anybody help? This is my code:

```
function photoUpload(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var progress = document.querySelector('.js-photoUploadBoxProgress');

    function updateProgress(evt) {
        var percentLoaded = Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
        if (percentLoaded < 100) {
            progress.style.width = percentLoaded + '%';
        }
    }
    progress.style.width = '0%';
    reader.onprogress = updateProgress;
    // loop for files
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                // stuff with photo upload
            };
        })(f);
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell what does console.log(evt.loaded) return please ? In updateProgress() it suppose to return a binary value i guess.

Comment: 57855 this is what's return

Comment: Can you try the same for evt.total ? i think they might be equal and due to the great speed of reading, the condition (percentLoaded < 100) is false and the uploadProgress fired only one time.

Comment: 33306 this i value of  evt.total

Comment: can you try to change (percentLoaded < 100) to (percentLoaded <= 100) ?

Comment: now i have 100% on start

Comment: it's cause the file reader is done really fast. And i guess the proper way is to let (percentLoaded < 100) and set 100% to progress-bar on reader.onload.
To do a relevant test, try a big picture file like this one http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d90/img/sample/pic_001b.jpg

Comment: I'm testing it on localhost so you could be right...